# document.write in StringBuilder?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, ashx, document.write

I am using a StringBuilder in an ashx file to return javascript.  It all works fine, except for one line...

```
javascript.Append("document.write(\"<script id=__ie_onload defer \" + \"src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>\");");
```

For readability, here is the unescaped version:

```
document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
```

If I comment out this line, my ashx file works like a charm!  If I keep it in, though, it won't even run.  Is there some sort of restriction on using a document.write statement in a StringBuilder?  Alternatively, is there a better way to write out Javascript from within .NET?  It has to be from .NET due to the need for using server variables.

Comment: The ashx file will not return anything if I keep that line in.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If you look at the HTTP response in Fiddler, what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unrecognized escape sequence in your closing `script` tag. `\/` is not a valid escape sequence.  You probably want:

```
javascript.Append("document.write(\"<script id=__ie_onload defer \" + \"src=javascript:void(0)></script>\");");
```

Or if you really want that `\/` sequence, then doubly-escape the `\`:

```
javascript.Append("document.write(\"<script id=__ie_onload defer \" + \"src=javascript:void(0)><\\/script>\");");
```

As a debugging tip, if your tools provide you with such poor feedback that you can't even see compilation errors, try creating a test application containing the problematic code. I copied your code into a console application, something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var javascript = new StringBuilder();
    javascript.Append(...
    Console.Write(javascript);
}
```

...and I saw the problem immediately on compilation:

> Unrecognized escape sequence

...with the problem sequence underlined.